# Tab control like in FireFox in native windows app

Tags: c++, c, winapi, mfc, tabcontrol

I would like to enable tabbing for my application. And so far it seems I could use a tab control. The problem with it is, though, that it creates a border around the client area. What I want, is more like a FireFox tab control, that only takes up a row in the application and doesn't create any frames around client area.

Does anyone know if it is possible with the default control?

I'm using MFC, but that shouldn't change things much I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also a CPropertySheet that's a good control. But so far it seems disabling and changing some things is simply impossible. No solution for the problem except full ownerdraw path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the tab control consists of two parts - the tab headers and the tab page. So you should be able to use the tab header only. It will take more work, but I think you can get what you want.

Look at CTabCtrl and CHeaderCtrl - will those do it? I've never customized them, but it seems possible.

Comment: Also - if you make the tab control frame wide enough, won't that work also? Then you would not be able to see frame.