# Handle DragDrop outside of control - DragEnd event?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

i'm are trying to mimic the behavior of web browsers in a WinForm application where you can drag and drop tabs in and out of the browser and create another instance of the it when you drop the tab somewhere with no existing tabs.

Currently the WinForm application only has one main `TabControl` and I was looking at the `DoDragDrop()` related events, but they seem to only work when you have two `TabControls` and move `TabPages` around those two.

Is there a way to make it work with only one `TabControl`? Meaning, If you `Drop` a `TabPage` out of the `TabControl` then it will create a new `TabControl` with the `TabPage` in it?

I can only think of using:

```
private void TabControl_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form newInstance = new Form();
    TabControl newTabControl = new TabControl();

    newInstance.Controls.Add(newTabControl);
    newTabControl.TabPages.Add(sender as TabPage);
    newInstance.Show();
}
```

but that is pretty crud and will create the new tab every time you leave the TabControl.

Comment: Start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4983361/10958092).

Comment: And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4130209/10958092).

Comment: @Alex Making a TabControl draggable is the easy part. What I want to do is allow it to drop on nothing in order to create the second control. Once the second control is created, the drag/drop is straight forward. The action to actually create the second control is what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for an event which raises at the end of drop, regardless of ending over your control or outside of the control.

You can rely on [`QueryContinueDrag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.querycontinuedrag?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and check if the action is `Drop`, then check the mouse position and for example if it's not inside your control, just create another window and add the selected tab into a tab control inside the new window.

```
private void tabControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        tabControl1.DoDragDrop(tabControl1.SelectedTab, DragDropEffects.All);
    }
}
private void tabControl1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TabPage)))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}
private void tabControl1_QueryContinueDrag(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == DragAction.Drop)
    {
        var tabPage = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
        if (!tabControl1.RectangleToScreen(tabControl1.Bounds).Contains(Cursor.Position))
        {
            var form = new Form();
            form.Text = tabPage.Text;
            var tabControl = new TabControl();
            tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
            tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            form.Controls.Add(tabControl);
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            form.Location = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - form.Width / 2,
                Cursor.Position.Y - SystemInformation.CaptionHeight / 2);
            form.Show();
            e.Action = DragAction.Cancel;

            //You can comment tabControl.TabPages.Add 
            //Then set e.Action = DragAction.Continue
            //Then the DragDrop event will raise and add the tab there.
        }
    }
}
private void tabControl1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(TabPage)))
    {
        var tabPage = (TabPage)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TabPage));
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
    }
}
```

For more advanced scenarios and to enhance the code:

- When start dragging, you can start dragging just if the mouse dragged at least for a specific points, for example 16 points. It's easy to calculate. Having p1 as mouse down point and p2 as mouse move point, and d as drag threshold. start dragging just in case `(p1.X-p2.X)*(p1.X-p2.X) + (p1.Y-p2.Y)*(p1.Y-p2.Y) > d*d`.
- You can use [`GiveFeedback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.givefeedback?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) event to disable default cursor of the mouse and instead show a more suitable cursor while dragging, easily by `e.UseDefaultCursors = false;` and setting `Cursor.Current = Cursors.SizeAll;` for example.
- You can encapsulate the logic and put it in a derived `TabControl`. Then in `DragEnter` and `DragLeave` events set a static property for tracking drop target. In case the drop-target has value, it means you are dropping on a derived tab control, otherwise it means you are dropping outside. Then drag and drop will be easily enabled for all your custom tab controls.
- You can close the tool form, after a drag and drop, in case the form doesn't contain any other tab.
- When adding the tab, you can insert it before/after the selected tab or the tab under cursor in target.

Comment: What you are trying to implement, has already been implemented in some libraries like [DockPanel Suite](http://dockpanelsuite.com/). So you may want to take a look at its [source code](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite) or give it a try.

Comment: You can see some of the enhancements in this example which I put on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6DUeiPx4). Copy and paste the example in a file in your project, build the project and then from toolbox, add an instance of `MyTabControl` to a form and run it.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking at `QueryContinueDrag`, but the docs made it seem like it could control the next drag event. I never thought of actually including it the method.